# Why can you switch branch in SVN with uncommited changes?

Tags: git, svn, branch

I come from git so maybe there's something I am missing. Find an example below:

Let's say I have the branch master and the branch release, I do some changes in master and I switch to release without committing the changes, in git I would get something like "Cannot switch branch with uncommitted changes, please commit or stash them". However in my recent experience with SVN at my new company not only I could switch the branch without problems but my changes were still there!

I am a little bit confused so some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In fact, you *can* get Git to switch branches in this case by adding `-m`, which makes it do a merge operation for such files. (I don't recommend doing this in general, and this has nothing to do with SVN, it's just an aside about Git.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it just is the way it is because the developers wanted it to be that way.

As you noted, `git` tells you how to get the `svn` behaviour (by doing `git stash && git checkout xyz && git stash pop`).

Long answer: I assume the reason why the `git` developers prefered to do is this way is because keeping your changes during a checkout is ultimately a 3-way-merge operation. These can cause conflicts and are generally "heavy". By enforcing a `git checkout` to be possible only on a clean working directory, you are guaranteed that `git` will either fail fast and painless, or be successful.

It's the same when you do a merge and your working directory is not clean. `git` will also deny that operation.

All of this is for your protection. The uncommitted working directory (and index) changes are not protected by a commit. If something goes wrong, they would be gone forever, with no way to recover. Failed merge conflict resolution is amongst the very, very few things that can go wrong when you work with `git`, and `git` has no possible way to avoid that (because the resolution is a human operation).

So, if `git` were to allow `checkout` or `merge` into an unclean working directory, it would have to do a `git stash` (or something similar) for you in the background; the design decision was simply to leave that to you, and to avoid weird constellations that could possibly lead to data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout a new working copy with the branch you need. With Subversion you can have unlimited number of working copies.